# What would it take to build a simple proxy server using ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I'm wondering how difficult it would be to build a proxy service upon/with ServiceStack.  Considering how fast ServiceStack is with Redis / serialization / etc., and how simple it is to implement the stack in general, this seems very tempting.  Anyone else attempt this?  How difficult would this be?

Comment: It would take "writing code" - have at it! But why use ServiceStack at all? I've used it before, but it seems like it "does too much", or rather "is designed for a different purpose", for a true proxy server (e.g.  [Squid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_(software))). A proxy really needs to get in quite close and comfortable with direct web requests .. and storage can be done by various means.

Comment: Why?  First, for the reasons mentioned in the question.  Its underlying components are incredibly fast and run smoothly on both Windows and Linux (via Mono).  IMHO there isn't a good C#/.NET proxy project out there and there is occasionally a need for a proxy that can be tweaked a programmatically / differently from something like Squid.

Comment: ServiceStack is *already* a middle layer (that is SS itself *relies* on a particular lower level service/interface), and it takes *writing code* to accomplish such a task. "What would it take to build a simple proxy server using XYZ?" - There is no suitable question here. I would imagine it would take only an hour or so to get a *very basic* proxy up. Go do it if you want.

Comment: One issue with directly using a middle layer like SS directly for a low-level operation like a *non-trivial* proxy, is that it doesn't necessarily replace the need to correctly handle requests directly (it is, after all, primarily based around a web-service endpoint) - e.g. past basic requests, it might requires a custom HttpHandlerModule anyway. Sure, you can use all the fun stuff ServiceStack has; but you can use most of the libraries/components directly anyway, or could use an entirely different library or access strategy.

Comment: @FredLackey : Great idea.  I cannot stand Squid or Linux.  It would be great to have a C#-based proxy server project.  Using Redis on the back end would really make it quick.

Comment: @RyanD'Baisse Would it make webscale?

Answer (score 6):

A new [Proxy Feature](http://docs.servicestack.net/proxy-feature) was added in [ServiceStack v4.5.10](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.10) that greatly simplifies creating a proxy where you can create a proxy by just registering a plugin, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new ProxyFeature(
    matchingRequests: req => req.PathInfo.StartsWith("/proxy"),
    resolveUrl:req => $"http://remote.server.org" + req.RawUrl.Replace("/proxy","/")) 
{
    // Use TransformResponse to rewrite response returned
    TransformResponse = async (res, responseStream) => 
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            var responseBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            var replacedBody = responseBody.Replace(
                "http://remote.server.org",
                "https://external.domain.com/proxy");
            return MemoryStreamFactory.GetStream(replacedBody.ToUtf8Bytes());
        }
    }
})
```

Which fill forward all requests to `/proxy` in your ServiceStack instance to `http://remote.server.org`.

#### Manually Creating a Reverse Proxy

The first entry in [ServiceStack's Request Pipeline](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations) lets your register Raw ASP.NET IHttpHandlers which can execute raw ASP.NET Handlers and take over executing the request from ServiceStack.

This will let you use a [use an ASP.NET IHttpHandler proxy like this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31329/Simple-Reverse-Proxy-in-C-2-0-description-and-depl) by registering it your AppHost, e.g:

```cs
this.RawHttpHandlers.Add(httpReq =>
    httpReq.PathInfo.StartsWith("/proxy")
        ? new ReverseProxy()
        : null);
```

This would tell ServiceStack to execute requests starting with `/proxy` with the custom ReverseProxy IHttpHandler.

If you want to use it in ServiceStack's self-hosts you would also have to change ReverseProxy to also inherit from ServiceStack's convenient `HttpAsyncTaskHandler` base class (or just implement [IServiceStackHandler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/Handlers/IServiceStackHandler.cs)), e.g:

```cs
public class ReverseProxy : HttpAsyncTaskHandler
{
    public override void ProcessRequest(IRequest req, IResponse res, 
        string operationName)
    {
        var httpReq = (IHttpRequest)req; //Get HTTP-specific Interfaces
        var httpRes = (IHttpResponse)res;

        // Create a connection to the Remote Server to redirect all requests
        var server = new RemoteServer(httpReq, httpRes);
        // Create a request with same data in navigator request
        HttpWebRequest request = server.GetRequest();

        // Send the request to the remote server and return the response
        HttpWebResponse response = server.GetResponse(request);
        byte[] responseData = server.GetResponseStreamBytes(response);

        // Send the response to client
        res.ContentType = response.ContentType;
        res.OutputStream.Write(responseData, 0, responseData.Length);
        server.SetContextCookies(response); // Handle cookies to navigator

        res.EndHttpHandlerRequest(); // End Request
    }

    public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        var httpReq = context.ToRequest("CustomAction");
        ProcessRequest(httpReq, httpReq.Response, "CustomAction");
    }

    ....
}
```

You would also have to refactor the implementation of [RemoteServer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31329/Simple-Reverse-Proxy-in-C-2-0-description-and-depl) in the example to work with ServiceStack's `IHttpRequest` / `IHttpResponse` interfaces.

If it's needed you can also access the underlying ASP.NET (or HttpListener) request objects with:

```cs
var aspNetReq = httpReq.OriginalRequest as HttpRequestBase; 
var aspNetRes = httpRes.OriginalResponse as HttpResponseBase;
```