# ServiceStack - As passthru to another ServiceStack service

Tags: c#, servicestack

I currently have an ServiceStack Service that does nothing but relay requests to an internal ServiceStack service.

The relay service is setup something like this (code made brief as an example):

```
public class RelayService : Service
{
    public SomeDTO Get(FetchSomething request)
    {
        try
        {
            return new JsonServiceClient(settings.OtherServiceURL).Get(request);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void Put(PersistSomething request)
    {
        try
        {
            new JsonServiceClient(settings.OtherServiceURL).Put(request);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is it best practice to new up a JsonServiceClient for each request? Or should I inject an instance?
2. Since the relay service can contain variations on Put/Get that return DTO's or void, is there a cleaner way to relay all calls to the backing ServiceStack service instead of having to duplicate each method in the relay service?  Is it possible to do this all in one or a few methods using Any()?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This previous answer for an example of a [generic reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21945905/85785) in ServiceStack.

The simplest and most generic approach in ServiceStack would be to register a [RawHttpHandler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations) that just forwards the Request to the downstream server and writes the Response to the Output Stream, e.g:

```
RawHttpHandlers.Add(_ => new CustomActionHandler((req, res) =>
{
    var bytes = req.InputStream.ReadFully();
    var proxyUrl = settings.OtherServiceURL.CombineWith(req.RawUrl);
    var responseBytes = proxyUrl.SendBytesToUrl(method: req.Verb,
        requestBody: bytes,
        accept:MimeTypes.Json,
        contentType: req.ContentType, 
        responseFilter: webRes =>
        {
            res.StatusCode = (int)webRes.StatusCode;
            res.StatusDescription = webRes.StatusDescription;
            res.ContentType = webRes.ContentType;
        });

    res.OutputStream.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
}));
```

In order to access the RequestStream you'll also want to tell ServiceStack to not inspect the FormData when creating the Request (as this forces reading the request body), which you can skip with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig { 
    SkipFormDataInCreatingRequest = true
});
```

Another approach would be to configure something like [IIS Application Request Routing and URL Rewriting](http://www.wrapcode.com/infrastructure/configure-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-and-arr-for-iis/) to use as a reverse proxy.